# Change font size for some parts in a markdown file when creating a .docx with pandoc

Tags: python, markdown, font-size, pandoc, cpu-word

I have a markdown file and I want to convert it into a .docx using pandoc inside python using `pypandoc` package:

```
 pypandoc.convert_file('file.md', 'docx', outputfile="file.docx")
```

I have some part in the .md (some tables) that in the docx file are too large and I want to recude the font size only for this part of text. I tried to wrap the specific part using `<font size="1"> </font>` without success.

How can I solve the problem and be able to share this .docx file that can be seen also form other person/computer ?

Answer (score 0):

I expect this is not possible. As the [documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#description) states (emphasis added):

> Because pandoc’s intermediate representation of a document is less
> expressive than many of the formats it converts between, one should
> not expect perfect conversions between every format and every other.
> Pandoc attempts to preserve the structural elements of a document, but
> ***not formatting details*** such as margin size. And some document
> elements, such as complex tables, may not fit into pandoc’s simple
> document model. While conversions from pandoc’s Markdown to all
> formats aspire to be perfect, conversions from formats more expressive
> than pandoc’s Markdown can be expected to be lossy.

Of course, you are attempting to convert Markdown to another format, so it seems like that should work. However, by using `<font>` tags you are reverting to raw HTML, which is not Markdown and cannot be represented in pandoc's "intermediate representation of a document" as anything except raw text for includsion when converting to HTML. Additionally, a `<font>` tag is not a "structural element," but rather a "formatting detail." Therefore, there would be no reason to expect pandoc to preserve it in conversion to any format other than HTML.

And that last bit is the clincher. Any alternate way of defining a font size is still a "formatting detail." It is simply not something which pandoc can be expected to preserve.